# how to check the specific word of a list contains int the string content in C#

Tags: c#, linq

i want to search the whole word if it matches with the string content.its matching with state, it should not match with state, it should match with stat
sample data

```
var DocContent = abc 123 stat//should match
xyz 444 
var DocContent = abc 123 state 222//should not match
xyz 444 

"matchIndicator":["stat","one"]

code 
MetaData.matchIndicator.Find(x => DocContent.Contains(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I don't get your question. What is `xyz 444`?  Furthermor some punctuation would be nice, I have no clue what "its matching with state, it should not match with state, it should match with stat sample data" should mean. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how you write a good question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split your text by the word delimiters, for example by empty space. Then you can use LINQ to check if any word is contained in the matchIndicator-array:

```
string DocContent = "abc 123 stat";//should match
string[] matchIndicator = {"stat", "one"};

string[] wordDelimiters = {" "};
bool match = DocContent.Split(wordDelimiters, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Any(word => matchIndicator.Contains(word, StringComparer.Ordinal));
```

You can change `StringComparer.Ordinal` to `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if desired.

Comment: it should check with any case like InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.but it should not match with State.

Comment: @krishnamohan: you haven't mentioned that in your question, but i have explained that in my answer anyway. The key of my answer is that you should check whole words not substrings as you did.

Comment: Why should he check whole words and nor substring? You haven't mentioned that in your answer. OP needed to check for substring.

Comment: @DongLi: op mentioned it should match with full word. If you look at his Sample and the comment you'll notice that stat matches but not state, because the full word is stat.